# changing path to GCC in .bashrc file

Tags: bash, gcc, gfortran

I have updated from gcc-4.5.8 to gcc-6.3.0. To use gcc-6.3.0, I loaded the modules in the following way:

```
cd /repos/software/7
```

(In this directory, there is a gcc/gcc-6.3.0 directory)

```
module avil
module load prs_software
module load gcc/gcc-6.3.0
```

By executing `gcc --version`, I see that I am now using gcc-6.3.0. However, when I execute `which gcc` and `which gfortran`, it points to `/usr/local/software/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc` and `/usr/local/software/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gfortran` , respectively. Clearly, this is not where I loaded gcc-6.3.0. Based on where I loaded the modules, the path the gcc and gfortran appears to be `/repos/software/7/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc` and `/repos/software/7/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gfortran`, respectively.

I would like to add this path to gcc to the environment variable PATH in my .bashrc file. I am not familiar with .bashrc. How should I do this?

Comment: As an aside, it's more appropriate to use `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc` for this -- the latter is for changes that aren't exported through the environment, and so which need to be rerun on every interactive shell; the former is used for things that only need to be run once per session.

Comment: There is a lot of information about this on [unix stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the bottom of your .bashrc file will append those two paths to the front of your path.

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/repos/software/7/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gcc:/repos/software/7/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/bin/gfortran"
```

Note, however, for you to see this change you will need to refresh your environment by sourcing your ~/.bash_profile file

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

I would also recommend that you create a backup copy of your .bashrc file prior to modifying. `cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc-ORIG`.  That way if something goes awry that you cannot sort out, you can simply delete your modified .bashrc `rm ~/.bashrc` and then `mv ~/.bashrc-ORIG ~/.bashrc` and then refresh your environment `source ~/.bash_profile` to get back to your original state.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, I found a solution. I just added `export PATH=/repos/software/7/gcc/gcc-8.3.0/bin:$PATH` to my .bashrc. It seemed to work after I sourced my .bash_profile. However, j_b's solution works fine as well, so I accepted their answer.